# animateTransition resets toView's frame origin to (0 , 0)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am having an issue when trying to use a custom transition between two view controllers. When I run a dismissal animation after the animation completes the toView's frame origin will reset to (0, 0):

[image]

The code for presenting and dismissing is like so:

```
class ConfirmEmailAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    let duration = 0.5
    var dismiss = false

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        if !dismiss {

            let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
            let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!
            let finalFrame = toView.frame
            toView.frame.origin.x += transitionContext.containerView()!.frame.size.width
            transitionContext.containerView()?.addSubview(toView)

            //Animate out
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
                fromView.frame.origin.x -= transitionContext.containerView()!.frame.size.width
                toView.frame = finalFrame
                }) { (Bool) -> Void in
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

            }


        }


        else {

            let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
            let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

            transitionContext.containerView()!.addSubview(toView)
            transitionContext.containerView()!.bringSubviewToFront(toView)


            //Animate out
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
                toView.center = transitionContext.containerView()!.center
                fromView.center.x += 400
                }) { (Bool) -> Void in

                    transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

            }

        }

        }


}
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Just want the view to animate back to it's original position and not (0,0)s